# How do i remove svg tags from wordpress 4.7

Tags: wordpress, svg

I'm using wordpress 4.7 and i have a simple html that i want to implement it on wordpress twentyseventeen theme but problem is wordpress injecting multiple svg tag. so  how do i remove or disable the svg,defs,symbol  whole things.Though search in the web unable to find any solution

Comment: Are you sure your question wouldn't be better asked here instead? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ Even there more details would be required to turn this into an acceptable question I imagine.

Answer (score 1):

add this in your functions.php :

```
remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'twentyseventeen_include_svg_icons', 9999 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it after theme setup:

```
function remove_parent_svg_icons()
    {
        remove_action('wp_footer', 'twentyseventeen_include_svg_icons', 9999);
    }
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_parent_svg_icons');
```